# Как скомпилировать libstdc++ статически?

Tags: g++, eclipse, c++, linux

Использую среду Eclipse для C++. Как скомпилировать libstdc++ статически, чтобы не зависеть от этой библиотеки при копировании на другие компьютеры?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/

Обратите внимание на последние три строки сообщения:

> Update: As of GCC 4.5 there is now a -static-libstdc++ compiler option which does what you'd expect it to do. (Thanks to Tim Hutt for pointing this out.)